# Is it possible to lock wordpress menu, so that only owner Admin can change it?

Tags: wordpress, menu

Is it possible to give user based permissions to edit wordpress menu? I have a situation where, I don't want to allow other authors or users to edit the main navigation menu. In simpler words, is it possible to lock the menu so that no one else can edit except my self?

Answer (score 0):

Role type "Editor", "Author", "Contributor" and "Subscriber" do not have permission to edit menu by default.

Only "**Super Admin**" or "**Admin**" can edit menu. More about [**Roles_and_Capabilities**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities)